# Google Tango: Youtube 360 Videos Not Working

Tags: android, youtube, google-project-tango, tango, 360-degrees

I have a Project Tango Android tablet. I have installed and updated the latest Youtube app. When I try and play any 360 Videos from Youtube they only play flat. No ability to pan.

Is there another setting one needs to check to enable 360 Youtube videos on a Google Tango Tablet. This is one of the reasons I purchased this tablet in the first place. I can play 360 videos on the Kolor site ok.

Anyone else that has a Tango tablet, are you able to play 360 Youtube videos?

Thanks for any advice.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,right now YouTube 360 is not integrated with Project Tango.
Google may let us known if it is available.